# Leading Zeros Getting Dropped Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I am copying a select into a ul for use in a mobile app.  Some of the values in the select options have leading 0s.  I'm using a custom attribute in the li elements to mimick the values in the select's options.

When I copy the value into the li:value, it loses the leading 0.  I've even tried creating the whole li as a liter string that I append to the outer ul.

```
html:
<select id="seltest">
<option value="011111">good bye</option>
</select>
<div id="container"></div>

javascript:
$("#container").append("<ul id='thefilter'></ul>");

$("#seltest option").each(function () {
  var optval = $(this).val();
  var strvar = '<li value=\"' + String(optval) + '\">' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
  alert(strvar);
  $("#thefilter").append(strvar);
  var lastli = $("#thefilter li:last");
  alert(lastli[0].outerHTML);  // now the value has lost the leading 0
});
```

Here's a fiddle to show an example: http://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/4RbH9/7/

Does anyone have an idea how to preserve the leading 0?  It seems like jQuery is modifying my text.

TIA!

Comment: In chrome there is leading zero

Comment: @zerkms: In Firefox, there isn't.  (in the last alert)

Comment: Note that where `s` is a string primitive, then `String(s)` simply returns the primitive value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser is actually enforcing the spec.  From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li):

`The only allowed value for this attribute is a number, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters.`

In my handful of years of web development I've never used the `value` attribute on a list item.  So, some of you might find this additional note of interest:

`This attribute was deprecated in HTML4, but reintroduced in HTML5.`

Comment: Nice find! But I think *the browser* is enforcing the spec, not jQuery.

Comment: OK - I guess that's what is going on.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right, but the primary reference should be [LI element specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), which also links to the [value attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value). MDN is often a useful complimentary reference. Note however that while the value is an integer, it is still a string value. I don't think you can say "jQuery is enforcing the spec", since it says nothing about trimming leading zeros.

Comment: It seems a bit of an inconsistency to me that select option tags can have value attributes that are strings, but li tags cannot.  Either way, I'll just use a custom attribute.  :-)

Comment: @richb01—there are many attributes that have a different type of value depending on the element, e.g. *width* can be CDATA or number, *type* can be input type, content type, style or button type. The first rule of web development is **read the related spec**.

Comment: I actually realized that I should have said browser instead of jQuery, but, a man needs his sleep and I decided the answer was good enough.  I edited my answer.  As for the reference to w3 instead of MDN... I prefer MDN since it's indexed better by Google and it's straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a custom attribute in the li elements

No, you aren't. There is a standard [*value*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute for [LI elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

I don't think this has anything to do with jQuery (other than it creates confusion between DOM properties and HTML attributes). In the following:

```
<ol>
  <li value="06" onclick="alert(this.value)">Show value property
  <li value="06" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('value'))">Show value attribute
</ol>
```

both IE and Firefox return `6` for both alerts. The only difference is that in the first case, the value is type number and in the second type string (since [getAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9) returns a string).

If you want to preserve the literal value, use a *data-* attribute on the LI.

Comment: you are correct. I did not realize that Value had been ressurected.  You are also correct that this is not jQuery - it's the browser that is enforcing the standard.  I was testing my code with IE10, FF and Safari.  IE10 and FF enforced it.  Thanks for your help!